# abi.encode and abi.decode arguments, including variable-sized arrays

Tags: assembly

I'm passing some arguments to a function and `abi.encode()`-ing them. Then I pass this `data` to another function where I `abi.decode()` it, but Im not entirely sure how to do it:

Arguments I'm encoding:

```
uint256    quantity
uint8      addresses_array_length
address[]  addresses_array
address[]  addresses_array2
// addresses_array2.length = addresses_array.length - 1, always
```

I then pass this data and I'd like to decode it in exactly the same format (i.e. `uint256`, `uint8`, `address[]` and `address[]`).

How should I do this?

From what I read I should do something like:

```
assembly { //is it necessary to do all this within this assembly struct?
    quantity := mload(add(data, 32))
    addresses_array_length := mload(add(data, 1))
    // Now how should I do for the arrays?
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I ran into a similar problem a while back trying to encode/decode dynamic arrays. I would suggest to only use fixed-size arrays for that.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been reading a bit more (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.4/assembly.html) and apparently it should be possible to pass dynamic arrays since the first 32bytes of data for the data regarding the array, represents the length, so I might not even need the variable `addresses_array_length`, but still not sure how to continue.

Comment: @Hiperfly What if `abi.decode` isn t used for variable length array but is instead used as arguments for functions in someone s else implementation? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/159866

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but if you are using `abi.encode` then you can use `abi.decode`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.4;


contract A {

    function foo() public {
        uint256 a = 1;
        uint8 b = 2;
        address[] memory c = new address[](3);
        address[] memory d = new address[](2);
        
        c[0] = msg.sender;
        d[1] = msg.sender;
        
        bytes memory x = abi.encode(a, b, c, d);
        bar(x);
    }
    
    
    function bar(bytes memory data) public view {
        (uint256 x, uint8 y, address[] memory z, address[] memory w) = abi.decode(data, (uint256, uint8, address[], address[]));
    
        require(z[0] == msg.sender, "First array");
        require(w[1] == msg.sender, "Second array");
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got in trouble for this issue. After I followed Ismael's answer, it works. Thanks very much.
I also tried to use js to encode array data and decode in solidity. It works.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3();

let array = ['0x50c439b6d602297252505a6799d84ea5928bcfb6', '0x8b9f9f4aa70b1b0d586be8adfb19c1ac38e05e9a', '0x6e11655d6ab3781c6613db8cb1bc3dee9a7e111f'];
let userData = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(
    ['address[]'], [array]
);

console.log(userData);
```