# How to really encode dynamicall length array of structs in Solidity ? Or how to use the Muliplex Feature of 0x?

Tags: solidity, arrays, 0x, solidity-0.6.x, abiencoderv2

I need to use [the Multiplex Feature of 0x](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc8c10815bE32536685d12cE8305425163f0c6897#code#F1#L237) in order to perform a specific trade that perform a UniswapV3 call followed by a `_FillOTCorder` using the `SelfBalance` feature of the [the Multiplex Feature](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc8c10815bE32536685d12cE8305425163f0c6897#code#F1#L237).

As this is a complex set of code, the best way to do it is to reuse the existing solidity code.
As the order need to be signed, I can’t call `multiplexMultiHopSellEthForToken` on the proxy contract directly : I need to encode almost the whole call off‑chain in a Solidity vm, then sign it.

The problem is the `multiplexMultiHopSellEthForToken` is using variable‑sized arrays as input function’s parameters.

Comment: There’s seems to be no public toolkits for encoding transactions for the `MultiplexFeature` which by the way is deployed only on the Ethereum mainnet.